# Dimension of a set

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
$T: V \to V $ is a linear map of an n-dimensioned vector space. Given the vector space:
$K=\lbrace X| X:V\to V , T\circ X=0\rbrace$. Find $\dim K$

**Thought**
We thought about setting about a new mapping $S: \text{Hom} (V,V) \to V$ s.t $K=\text{Ker}S$ If somehow we were able to prove that this map is surjective then $\dim K=n^2-n$. We haven't found a way to prove that. Is this direction correct? How do we prove it if so? If not , what is a better direction?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this cannot be correct, for the following reason: it takes nothing about the transformation $T$ in to account. In particular: consider the cases where $T$ is the identity mapping and $T$ is the 0-mapping.  They should have very different behavior here!

**HINT:** The condition that $X\in K$ is equivalent to the condition that the image of $V$ under $X$ is contained in the null space of $T$.